# How do you write "The cold and lonely nights"

Tags: meaning

I believe it is "die kalten und einsam Nächte" but honestly I'm not sure if the arrangement of the sentence is correct, and if the word "einsam" means lonely

Comment: Welcome to the German Language StackExchange. What makes you doubt "einsam = lonely"?

Comment: Meaning and syntax are correct, but parallel adjectives have to be inflected in parallel: "kalten und einsam*en*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. You are right but there is a little bit wrong: “Die kalten und einsamen Nächte” is right. You forgot the *en* in *einsam**en.*** *Einsamen* is the plural. So you have to use it.

Comment: I corrected my answer. Thank you @Jan and chirlu. Please upvote my answer if it is now good. (Please upvote because the final/edited answer has to be voted and not the bad version)